# Python requests client JSON rejected by Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, python-requests, jackson

I am trying to send JSON using Python requests to a Spring Boot 3.2 server with Jackson installed.

The Python JSON is generating a 400 error from the Spring Boot server and the error log from Spring Boot states:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.monkey.signalsdb.model.Timer`
(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from 
String value ('{ "start_date_time": "20240227-215731", "channel": 59, "snr": [ 15.5, 21.1, 26.8 ], 
"dbfs": -23.56, "lat": -36.7453, "lon": 174.6837, 
....
"end_date_time": "20240227-215731" }')]
```

If the JSON generated by Python is pasted into Postman it posts to the endpoint with correct response 201.

I am generating the JSON in my python data class with:

**With toJSON method on class**

```
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps({"start_date_time" : self.start_date_time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), \
                           "channel" : self.channel, \
                             "snr" : self.snr, \
                             "dbfs" : self.dbfs, \
                             "lat" : self.lat, \
                             "lon" : self.lon, \
                             ...
                             "end_date_time" : self.finish_date_time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")}, \
                            indent = 4)
```

I have been trying to send the JSON using a Juypter notebook for fast testing with the pseudo code, and also using the toJSON method on my class.

**Tests So Far**

1. I can cut and paste the JSON generated by my custom `toJSON` method on my data class into Postman and it posts fine as is.
2. Creating a test string and sending it:

   testjson = '{ "start_date_time": "20240227-215731", "channel": 59, "snr": [ 15.5, 21.1, 26.8 ],
   "dbfs": -23.56, "lat": -36.7453, "lon": 174.6837, "carrier_freq": 160.12,
   ...
   "end_date_time": "20240227-215731" }'

   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*'}
   req = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/', json = testjson, headers=headers)

But the result is the same JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance - both using my `testjson` string of the JSON and the `toJSON` method.

3. Using built in JSON method :

   req = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/', json = ct, headers=headers)
   TypeError: Object of type ChickTimer is not JSON serializable

and

```
req = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/', json = ct.toJSON(), headers=headers)
Status Code: 400, Response: <bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>
```

4. Using testjson string with data:
   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*'}
   req = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/', json = testjson, headers=headers)

   This works. But I would like to get it working with the built in json method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the `json: testjson` part. That makes `requests` convert the string into JSON. The result is a JSON string.

From the source code of `requests`:

```py
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) A JSON serializable Python object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
```

Either don't convert to JSON yourself, or use `data` instead of `json`.

Comment: Thank you using `data=` worked. If I wanted it to work with `json=` do I just give it my dataclass instance? Because when I try that I get 'TypeError: Object of type ChickTimer is not JSON serializable'

Comment: A little more testing has revealed 'data = testjson' works. 'data = ct' and 'data = ct.toJSON' does not.

Comment: Something in your `ChickTimer` class prevents it from being serializable, so that indeed leaves `data = testjson`. You should also be able to use `data = ct.toJSON()`. The `()` are necessary to make it a function call and not a function itself.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I will debug the built in serialisation and post back here.